# Export to PDF from static HTML in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app where i have external static html file which i wanted to parse and export to PDF format in angularJs

Can some one help me on the same.

Thanks,
Prasant

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you should check using a Javascript PDF library, like this one: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF